# 4K monitor shows no picture

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, xserver, nvidia-settings

On ubuntu 16.04 my acer monitor shows no picture with 4K resolution. It was working with live cd with 4k resolution but on installed ubuntu only works with full hd. 4k is choosable but shows no picture. If I use nvidia driver the laptop freezes after setting display settings with 4k. I tried with hdmi and displayport cables. On windows and ubuntu live cd the 4K resolution works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found solution, the problem was the refresh rate of 60 Hz which my gpu apparently doesn't support - set it to 30:

```
xrandr --output DP-1-1 --mode 3840x2160 --rate 30
```

DP-1-1 varies - run xrandr to se the name of the monitor

Comment: +1 Good HDMI 30 Hz fact to know too!